# "import atom" in gdata-python-client, which atom

Tags: python, gdata-api

I was running through the gdata-python-client, when I tried to run the code it failed as the module atom isn't installed.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/contacts/contacts_example.py

When I try and do a pip install of atom

```
sudo pip install atom
```

it seems to pick up "Automated Testing on Mac", which doesn't compile on ubuntu.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/atom/0.9.2

And isn't right any way as reading the code suggests that the atom module used here is for atom feed generation.

What is the correct module for atom to install in the gdata world and can it just used as is or does it need to be corrected in the file:

```
import pyatom as atom
```

for example

Comment: I think its a probably bug of pip cause to install mac tests by easy_install you should pass atomac not atom and for import you should use "atomac" name "import atomac". Try install atom module by easy_install or setup it manual.

Comment: I think I may have confused you, I am not looking for atomac, but that is what I am getting, the link listed above states that there is a naming collision in the package index.  What I can't figure out though, in the gdata case, what atom refers to, so I am unable to download it and manually install it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I don't know why it can't find it either but it's a module which should be part of gdata:

Atom is installed as part of gdata. It installs in folder /usr/lib/python2./dist-packages/atom
and gdata:
usr/lib/python2./dist-packages/gdata

Try to locate it, otherwise uninstall gdata, get the latest one:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list

And install it manually :)

Note that it doesn't work with python 3

It supports up to python 2.7.

Hope that helps